# NodeJs UI type Auto documentation

Tags: node.js, documentation

I have a NodeJs API application repository. I want to get a Documentation for the repository automatically.
for example: If run npm documentation, then I should get a list of all routes of my API with expected parameters and results in a UI form. Not like the postman tool.
Are there any online NPM packages/Tools for my requirement?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [swagger](https://swagger.io/)?

Comment: @plumbn
alternative of swagger